# using an array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I am currently trying to figure out how to store two sets of values, t and y, in my program so that I can plot these data points on a graph. I believe the correct method is to use an array, but I am not sure how to proceed.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


t = 0.0
y = 0.0
u = 0.0
F = 0.2
Wd = 2*3.14
w0 = 1.5*Wd
b = w0/4


h= 0.05

while (t <= 5.95):
    m1 = u
    k1 = (-w0**2)*np.sin(y) + u*(1-2*b) + F*(w0**2)*np.cos(Wd*t)
    m2 = u + (h / 2.) * k1
    t_2 = t + (h / 2.)
    y_2 = y +(h / 2.) * m1
    u_2 = m2
    k2 = (-w0**2)*np.sin(y_2) + u_2*(1-2*b) + F*(w0**2)*np.cos(Wd*t_2)
    m3 = u + (h / 2.) * k2
    t_3 = t + (h / 2.)
    y_3 = y + (h / 2.) * m2
    u_3 = m3
    k3 = (-w0**2)*np.sin(y_3) + u_3*(1-2*b) + F*(w0**2)*np.cos(Wd*t_3)
    m4 = u + h * k3
    t_4 = t + h
    y_4 = y + h * m3
    u_4 = m4
    k4 =  (-w0**2)*np.sin(y_4) + u_4*(1-2*b) + F*(w0**2)*np.cos(Wd*t_4)
    t = t + h
    y = y + (h / 6.) * (m1 + (2 * m2) + (2 * m3) + m4)
    u = u + (h / 6.) * (k1 + (2 * k2) + (2 * k3) + k4)
    print t, y
```

Comment: So what doesn't work? What are you struggling with?

Comment: I want to take the printed values that I get from my python code and plot them on a graph with t being the x axis and y being the y axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While printing `t` and `y` use `plt.scatter(t, y)`
After the loop use `plt.show()`

Or

You can save `t` and `y` in array `T` and `Y` and later use `plt.scatter(T, Y)` and `plt.show()` to plot.

[image]

To draw line

```
T, Y = [], []
```

## loop starts

```
....
....
t = t + h
y = y + (h / 6.) * (m1 + (2 * m2) + (2 * m3) + m4)
T.append(t)
Y.append(y)
....
....
```

## loop ends

```
plt.plot(T, Y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to include a line through all the points?

Comment: Check answer please.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just put your values to the lists and run plot on them afterwards:

```
...
ts = []
ys = []
while (t <= 5.95):
    ...
    y = y + (h / 6.) * (m1 + (2 * m2) + (2 * m3) + m4)
    u = u + (h / 6.) * (k1 + (2 * k2) + (2 * k3) + k4)
    ts.append(t)
    ys.append(y)

plt.plot(ts,ys)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!